# Is OpenLayers appropriate for creating maps of a fantasy world?

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

Please excuse my ignorance, I've been directed here from Stack Overflow where I've been looking at a variety of HTML5/JQuery packages to create a map of a fantasy world that exists in a game I maintain a player fansite for.

The features I desire are

- Free to use
- Requires no server side installations
- Allows for markers/annotations
- Supports layers (for example roads)
- Able to be zoomed/scaled
- Able to switch from a "global" view to a more "local" map (eg from continents down to cities and streets)
- Requires no knowledge of GIS by the end user beyond the sort of experience Google Maps offers
- Supports some sort of overlay when a region is moused over/into

I did not consider open layers because I thought it might be too slow or overkill for my project, but as I'm looking at a variety of jquery solutions which only work together questionably well I'm now willing to consider a more substantial learning investment if it will help me achieve my goal.

Comment: Thus far I have satisfied the following criteria: free to use, no server side installations, supports for layers, zoomed/scaled.  I continue to explore and should I complete all my own criteria I'll post an answer.

Comment: I would say yes to all of them. You can mix any number of layers and zoom levels. OL3 has a somewhat steep learning curve, (compared to Google Maps), but also supports more formats and your own backdrops,  but the examples are quickly growing.

Comment: Have you also looked at Leaflet JS? It's simpler than OL (which is a great bit of kit BTW) and may be quicker to implement than OL. The Simple CRS (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#defined-crs-l.crs.simple) should be of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitively yes. OpenLayers3 is a viable solution for what you need.
Maybe with the exception of "GIS knowledge", it is a GIS tool so probably you will need to learn some GIS concepts.

Another great option is Leaflet. Initially it seems easy to start than OpenLayers but has its own limitations.

You can try to create a relatively small sample using both libraries with a raster layer, a vector layer (roads) and manage some markers. So you can learn from that experience.

IMO, OpenLayers tries to be a more "all in one" and "closed" solution. It provides lots of layers, formats, controls, etc but can be hard to extent it.
Leaflet offers initially (without plugins) less features and is more "open" to be extended. Of course extend any of them is not trivial.